# Accessing an Azure App Service on unusual ports

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My application exposes multiple web services on multiple ports, e.g. 4500-4513. I have deployed it on Azure as an app service but the resulting service is only listening on ports 80 and 443. Is this configurable so I can access it on the required ports or must I deploy it on an Azure VM to have this level of control on networking?

Comment: As I answered elsewhere (including the question I marked yours a duplicate of): you may only use 80 & 443 in web apps.

Comment: You can use App Service Environment and set the rules: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic

Comment: So this is the problem I have. There's a sentiment (from a Microsoft worker which gives it gravitas) that it's only 443 and 80, so why does the other article comment, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic, exist?

Comment: App Service Environments (ASE) may be deployed to a virtual network with other parts of your app. The inbound network control, referenced by the article, is about IP-level access control lists. Nowhere does it state that additional ports may be opened inbound from the outside world. The ASE gives you much more freedom within an internal vnet.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - ASEs don't let you open additional ports aside from 80/443. It offers the ability to apply IP-level ACLs to ports (which becomes key when blocking inbound traffic from the outside world, and allowing traffic specifically from a vnet.

Comment: Also note: ASE is quite a different thing: a superset of standard Web Apps: significantly more resources (dedicated resources) and features.

Comment: Thanks David Makogon, I think the confusion stems from between App Service Environments being read as App Service environments (not lower-case e). They aren't the environment your App Service runs in, they're another thing entirely. I get it now.